Powershell append date when moving file
Novice here with Powershell everyone - so appreciate the help! I have an existing script that was left for me that essentially moves pdf files into folders of the same name in the same directory.
Which is great - until you have a pdf with the same name that needs to go into the folder without overwriting the old one. Script is -
$folder = 'V:\Files'
Set-Location $folder
Get-ChildItem *.pdf | Move-Item -Destination { $_.BaseName.}

Is there a way that I can append a date onto the end of the pdf and move it into the folder so moving forward it will not error out?
So for example, if I have pdf '123456789' that was created 5/1/2023 and pdf '123456789' created 5/1/2024, it will move them both into existing folder '123456789' as:
'123456789_05_01_2023.pdf'
'123456789_05_01_2024.pdf'

I have tried looking at various sites for scripts that work, but like I said - a novice and looking for a bit of help to understand how to do something like that. Thank you!

Does this answer your question? How do I concatenate strings and variables in PowerShell?

You're pretty close with your current code, just need to concatenate the .BaseName with the .CreationTime property and lastly to the .Extension property. To get the Date format in your question you can use the string format MM_dd_yyyy. Putting all together the could would be:
$folder = 'V:\Files'
$destination = 'X:\path\to\myDestination'

Get-ChildItem -Path $folder *.pdf | Move-Item -Destination {
    Join-Path $destination -ChildPath ('{0}_{1:MM_dd_yyyy}{2}' -f $_.BaseName, $_.CreationTime, $_.Extension)
}

